# Build failed on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

In VSTS i am attempting to run a build using the .NET Desktop Template. I am not using Nuget so i deleted that entry but i keep having an error after running.

Build Error:
[image: build error]

Here is the mappings. The .sln file is located in $FinTechProject/FinTech/FinTech/FinTech.sln

Get Source Mappings:
[image: get souces mappings]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can't find the solution file. The workspace mappings look fine based on what you said, so the only thing I can think of is that the solution file isn't actually in source control. Can you click the ellipsis next to the path to the solution for the Visual Studio Build task and select the solution?

Comment: Can you share the logs for "Get Sources" step?

Answer (score 0):

Try specify exact path to sln file, without wildcards. That should help.